# Facebook ShareDialog Strange "dot" in message

Tags: android, facebook

I have little problem when i post facebook message on wall via ShareDialogBuilder i get strange result on wall.

This dot visible on image: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/499x274q90/673/R0ZUo9.png

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
                .setRef("REF")
                .setDescription("description")
                .setApplicationName("TitleTitle")
                .setCaption("Caption")
                .setName("Name")
                .setPlace("Place")
                .build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

Every combination of parameters don't change the results. Can any one help? Maybe i have forget to set something on Facebook Developer page of My App?

Comment: If you PM me your app id, I can have a look for you. It looks like your app name may be misconfigured.

Comment: hey did you find a solution. I too am getting similar problems

Comment: Hi, i have reported this issue and they fixed it in one week : )

Comment: I am having a very similar issue. could you tell me where you reported the problem?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ If you start write smth in Search Box there will  appear button "Create New Bug"